# Toggling visibility of view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-relativelayout, tablelayout

One of the layouts shows toggling of view's visibility.The layout have two buttons say b1 and b2.Both buttons reveals/expand respective RelativeLayout. On button click, the visibility of RelativeLayout will toggle.

RelativeLayout which gets expanded on b1 click has edittext implementation.
Where as b2 expands RelativeLayout with TableLayout in it.
This is what I'm trying to show:
[image]

The problem is, sometimes the TableLayout is not visible.Like so:
[image]

Here is the onClick implementation:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSearchByName:
            if (rlSearchByName.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                rlSearchByName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                rlSearchByName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnSearchByPartNo:
            if (rlSearchByPartNo.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                rlSearchByPartNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                rlSearchByPartNo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            break;
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchByName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/search_by_name"
        android:textColor="@color/orange" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlSearchByName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#30828282"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tv_search_by_name"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llNameField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etLastName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:textColorHint="#60828282" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:textColorHint="#60828282" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etMiddleName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Middle Name"
                android:textColorHint="#60828282" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llNameField"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:text="@string/search"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnReset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:text="@string/reset"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchByPartNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/search_by_part_no"
        android:textColor="@color/orange" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlSearchByPart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#30828282"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/trPart12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trPart1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trPart2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/trPart34"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trPart3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trPart4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llResultView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:text="@string/search_results"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
make two variablr
private boolean first;
private boolean second;

once you click on first buton
then check condition like:


if(first){
//visible
first=false;
}else{
//invisible
first=true;

}
```